# Reshaping a weird list in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

Here in Python, I have a list like this:

```
array = 
[[[0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,1],[1,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0]],
[[0,1,0],[1,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,0,1]],
[[0],[1],[0],[1]],
[[1],[1],[0],[1]]]
```

I want to reshape it into:

```
array = 
[[[0,0,1,0],[0,1,0],[0],[1]],
[[0,0,0,0],[1,0,0],[1],[1]],
[[1,0,0,0],[0,0,1],[0],[0]],
[[0,1,0,0],[0,0,1],[0],[1]]]
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: 2nd row 2nd col should it be [1,0,0]?

Comment: Are you flipping it over the top left-bottom right line?

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: Is this suppose to be a transpose?

Comment: Whats the logic ?

Comment: It looks like you're just trying to transpose a list of lists? If so, that's just `zip`. For example, `array = list(zip(*array))`.

Comment: Also, this is tagged `numpy`, and `arrays`, but your code shows a list of lists, not a numpy array. and you even refer to it as a list. So… where is numpy supposed to be involved here? Do you want to convert the result into a 2D array? Do you actually have a 2D array instead of a list of lists? Do you just want to use numpy as an intermediate step but go from a list of lists to a list of lists? Or…?

Comment: Anyway, I closed this as a dup of the canonical non-numpy transposing question, which has answers showing how to use `zip` and explaining why it works and everything. If you have or want a numpy array, please let us know and we can find a better duplicate that explains numpy's `.T` property for transposing.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, given

```
array = [[[0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,1],[1,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0]],
        [[0,1,0],[1,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,0,1]],
        [[0],[1],[0],[1]],
        [[1],[1],[0],[1]]]
```

Do

```
import numpy as np
>>> np.array(array).T

array([[list([0, 0, 1, 0]), list([0, 1, 0]), list([0]), list([1])],
       [list([0, 0, 0, 1]), list([1, 0, 0]), list([1]), list([1])],
       [list([1, 0, 0, 0]), list([0, 0, 1]), list([0]), list([0])],
       [list([0, 1, 0, 0]), list([0, 0, 1]), list([1]), list([1])]],
```

Comment: I've tried this and also np.transpose and both did what I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: So why don't you upvote and mark RafaelC's answer?